# Where is the verb in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, american-english

I can't seem to find the verb in this sentence. May I ask where it may be?

> The symptoms can be so intense that they become debilitating, distinguishing those who suffer from the disorder from those with normal anxieties.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The verb in the main clause is *can be*.

Comment: @StoneyB  what is the grammar structure of the phrase starting with "distinguishing"?  It *looks* similar to a participle phrase but it *feels* like something else entirely, like the start of a separate sentence.

Comment: @Andrew It *is* a supplementary participle clause, commenting on the significance of the main clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more than one verb in this sentence.

> The symptoms **can be** so intense that they **become** debilitating, **distinguishing** those who suffer from the disorder from those with normal anxieties.

This is because the sentence contains multiple clauses. It could be separated as follows (although it doesn't convey quite the same meaning), but to show how the verbs fit:

> The symptoms **can be** (so) intense. They **become** debilitating. This **distinguishes** those who suffer from the disorder from those with normal anxieties.

In the more meaningful construction you get the cause-and-effect message with the communication that the symptoms *in extremis* become debilitating.

> The symptoms **can be** so intense *that* they **become** debilitating,

and that this effect (when the symptoms are debilitating) identifies those people who suffer from this disorder (and that those people are not "merely" anxious).

Also, **can** is an auxiliary verb, so **can + be** are auxiliary and main verb in that clause.

Answer (score 2):

In the main part of the sentence the verb is "can be".

> The symptoms **can be** so intense ..

The second part of the sentence (everything after the comma) is something like a [participle phrase](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm) (actually called a "supplementary participle clause") that modifies the subject *the symptoms*.

> [The symptoms] **distinguish** those who suffer from ...